# echo BEL character without new line in batch code?

Tags: audio, batch-file, bell

Using the Bel Character in cmd (the CTRL+G character) I can make a sound in my batch file. However, because of how that works, it makes a new line. Is there a way I could not make a new line when making the sound?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using this:

```
Echo | set /p=“Ctrl+G”
```

Where ctrl+g is the Bel character.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [link](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3857) - the good thing is that is a copy-paste-able code without need of obscure characters that can be misinterpreted:

```
@echo off
setlocal

::Define a Linefeed variable
set LF=^


::above 2 blank lines are critical - do not remove.
call :hexprint "0x0B" BEL
echo --%BEL%--

exit /b

:hexPrint  string  [rtnVar]


  for /f eol^=^%LF%%LF%^ delims^= %%A in (
    'forfiles /p "%~dp0." /m "%~nx0" /c "cmd /c echo(%~1"'
  ) do if "%~2" neq "" (set %~2=%%A) else echo(%%A

exit /b
```